# Using POST parameters in WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I need to use get_header action to hook onto into my functions.php, so that I can check if the request is being sent to a proper page, but at that point in time, $_POST is empty, probably because of redirect. Is there a way to somehow pass that info to my function:

```
add_action('get_header', 'handle_app_post');
```

Comment: You will need to use an action that is triggered before any data is sent. Try using the `init` action.

Comment: add_action( 'init', 'handle_app_request' ); in callback function I have echo json_encode($_POST); which should return the superglobal value to the app that's making POST request, but instead it returns empty array.

Comment: Are you sure it is a `POST` request rather than just a `GET` request. Are you creating the request with a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to WordPress developers, no, this is not possible due to internal redirects in WordPress.